# AS3 + Starling - Find Unknown Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

I have legacy code project. While Starling is running sometimes some Sprite appears and covers all application.

In pure flash I used "console" https://code.google.com/p/flash-console/wiki/GettingStarted to get object hierarhy in display tree. But it doesn`t work for Starling.

My idea is to add some listener to root, cause this Sprite is in display list tree.
And find who is this Spite's parent.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> And find who is this Spite's parent. Is it possible?

If you are trying to find a display object, and you have no idea where it is coming from, one thing you could try doing is in a frame event, keep track of all the new sprites that are added to the display list. Then you can work backwards from there. Eg.

```
  // keep track of unique display objects
  private var _displayList:Array = [];
  public function Main()
  {
      addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, trackDisplayList );
  }

  private function trackDisplayList( event:Event ):void
  {
      trackAsset( stage );
  }

  private function trackAsset( asset:* ):void
  {
      var i:int = -1;
      while( ++i < asset.numChildren )
      {
          var child:* = asset.getChildAt( i );
          if ( _displayList.indexOf( child ) == -1 )
          {
              _displayList.push( child );
              trace( "tracking display object: " + child.name );
          }
          if ( child.numChildren > 0 )
          {
              trackAsset( child );
          }
      }
  }
```

Hopefully you don't have a boat load of sprites to sort through! This is one way you could recursively check all your unique display objects.